# How should I write $\int^x f(t)\,dt$? I want to formally get rid of the constant

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

if I write:

$$\int f(x)\,dx=g(x)+C$$

where $C$ is a constant.

I want to get only $g(x)$

How should I write it directly on the integral?

Comment: you know what is a [free variable and a bound variable ?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables) and you should forget the notation $\int f(x) dx$ and replace it by $\int_a^x f(t) dt$

Comment: Ok, i think I have to explaint my question better

Comment: I mean I dont want the "constant" part of the integral that is in the middle

Comment: what is the advantage of writing $g(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt$ ? (or even more general $g(x) = C+\int_a^x f(t) dt$)

Comment: I want an undefined integral without constant, how should I write?

Comment: if you don't like $g(x) = C+\int_a^x f(t) dt$ then write instead $f(x) = g'(x) \ \ \ $

Comment: a will remain if I use @user1952009 notation

Comment: Just write the indefinite integral as $\int^x f(x')\,dx'$.  Does that suffice?

Comment: $g(x) = C+ \int_a^x f(t) dt$ is often shortened $g(x) = \int f(x) dx$ but it is error prone (because it is ambiguous), so you should really avoid it for now

Comment: @Dr.MV I didn't know if it was right to write in this way. $\int^{x}f(x′)dx′$

Comment: It represents any function the derivative of which is $f(x)$.

Comment: @Dr.MV you answered my question, post it.

Comment: shortening a notation but making it ambiguous is not a good idea in general, even if we often do it in maths, because notations are always a compromise : between readability, and rigour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested by the OP, here is one possible notation.

Write $g(x)=\int^x f(x')\,dx'$ where $g(x)$ is any function the derivative of which is $g'(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: Why did this receive a down vote?

Comment: I think @user1952009 didn't like your answer as they said "shortening a notation but making it ambiguous is not a good idea in general, even if we often do it in maths, because notations are always a compromise : between readability, and rigour. "